# How can I send mail with rails without a template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

In my Rails 3 project, I want to send some simple notification emails. I don't need to make a template for them or do any logic. I just want to fire them off from various places in the system.

If I were doing this in an arbitrary ruby script I would use [pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony). However, I'd like to still use the rails mail facilities and configuration, so that I get the same reliability and setup that I have for the rest of the mail in my system.

What's the most simple way to do this? Ideally there would be some method like

```
ActionMailer.send(:to => 'foo@example.com', :subject =>"the subject", :body =>"this is the body")
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 2.3 or 3.0?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The simplest way to send mail in rails 3 without a template is to call the `mail` method of `ActionMailer::Base` directly followed by the `deliver` method,

For ex, the following would send a plain text e-mail:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  from: "me@example.com",
  to: "you@example.com",
  subject: "test",
  body: "test"
).deliver
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail gives you all the header options and also ideas about the how to send a multipart/alternative email with text/plain and text/html parts directly.

Comment: This is awesome and I can confirm works in Rails 4 as well.

Comment: and rails 5.1.0 too

Answer (score 13):

Rails 5 users may find the accepted answer (using `format.text {...}`) doesn't work; at least I was getting an exception because Rails was looking for a view.

Turns out there's a section in the Rails Guide called [Sending Emails without Template Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering)and all one needs to do is supply :content_type and :body options to `mail()`. E.g.:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email
    mail(to: params[:user].email,
         body: params[:email_body],
         content_type: "text/html",
         subject: "Already rendered!")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views) is little example from Rails Guides which uses `render` method. I didn't try it, but if it works as `render` in cotrollers, then you can just use:

```
render :text => "Your message"
```

or

```
render :text => my_message
```

Where `my_message` is a parameter.

You can just wrap it in a method which you can call from every place you want.

#### Updated Rails 3.2.8

In this version of Rails I had to do it like this:

```
def raw_email( email, subject, body )
  mail(
    :to => email,
    :subject => subject
  ) do |format|
    format.text { render :text => body }
  end
end
```

Comment: I considered this. It's pretty simple, but still requires making an `ActionMailer` model with a method. I was hoping there was maybe something even more simple, but if not this is the best choice.

Comment: Don't forget to add FROM header if you are sending mail to gmail. I've spent an hour figuring out why my mails aren't delivered and this was the reason.

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_simple_message(options)
    mail(options.except(:body)) do |format|
      format.text { render :text => options[:body] }
    end.deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: Would be cool if ActionMailer came with a "default notifier" like this. Maybe I should make a gem…

Comment: I think that `deliver` should not be in mailer's method. Instead it should be called during using mailer, like in default mailer usage

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ActionMailer::Base` like in [KMG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974849/5328826), if you want to use your `ApplicationMailer` (which may have a default from address already), you can:

```rb
ApplicationMailer.new.mail(
  to: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'subject',
  body: 'body'
).deliver
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who land here and need to include ATTACHMENTS, this works:

```
mail = ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  from: 'tony@tigers.com',
  to: 'pooh@bears.com',
  subject: 'Interspecies cooperation',
  content_type: "text/html",
  body: 'Yo.'
)
mail.attachments["results.json"] = some_json_string_in_this_case
mail.deliver
```