# SendGrid and Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to set up SendGrid on my Rails app, I've been following this: http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

So far I've setup my `config/environment.rb`

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => *********, 
  :password => *********, 
  :domain => *********, 
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Made a new file called `app/models/notifier.rb` which contains

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  include SendGrid
  default :from => "*****@******.com"

  # send a signup email to the user, pass in the user object that contains the user's email address
  def signup_email(user)
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => "Thanks for signing up" )
  end
end
```

In the rails console, this is what happens.

```
>> @new_user = User.new(:email => 'blah@blah.com')
 => #<User id: nil, email: "blah@blah.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
>> @new_user.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 23 Apr 2013 01:21:17 UTC +00:00], ["email", "blah@blah.com"], ["updated_at", Tue, 23 Apr 2013 01:21:17 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
>> Notifier.signup_email @new_user
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template notifier/signup_email with "mailer". Searched in:
* "notifier"
```

What am I doing wrong?  I don't see why I would need a template.  I'm new to Rails so please forgive me if this is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ActionMailer` defaults to using a template in Rails.  You should check out [the mailer guide for rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), it has more details than I'm about to describe here.

To fix the problem, you should create a template in `app/views/notifier/signup_email.html.erb` with some content.

---

As an aside, if you want to send an email without using a template, you need to invoke the `deliver` function immediately after creating the mailer.  See this stack overflow question for details:

[How can I send mail with rails without a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916557/how-can-i-send-mail-with-rails-without-a-template)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It might be worth noting that I kept on receiving template errors until I included `:body => "blah blah"` in my mail call.  Otherwise it looks for a template to fill the body.

Answer (score 0):

def signup_email(user)
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => "Thanks for signing up" )
end

replace by

def signup_email(user)
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => "Thanks for signing up", :body => "hello" )
  end