# How can I compress/minify an email in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, actionmailer, minify

Some emails we're sending are getting clipped by gmail, so I'm trying to make them smaller. The biggest effect is when I run the email through a minifier like: http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Now I'm trying to figure out how to minify the the emails I send with ActionMailer, that I send like:

```
NewsletterMailer.newsletter_email(@newsletter).deliver_later
```

I realize there are compression gems, but I'm not sure how to utilize those when ActionMailer is doing the rendering.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try [htmlcompressor](https://github.com/paolochiodi/htmlcompressor) gem?

Comment: But I need ActionMailer to do it, right? I'm not simply passing a big string to be email, ActionMailer is doing the rendering.

Comment: Render your email using ApplicationController.renderer.render(). Complete with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916557/how-can-i-send-mail-with-rails-without-a-template).

Comment: Florent, What about Rails 4?